# IE10 Blur using SVG and background-size: cover;

Tags: html, css, svg, internet-explorer-10

I am developing a page which allows the User to display a custom background image on a div which is then blurred via CSS.

However in IE10+ CSS Blur isn't available.

My current CSS working across browsers and mobile except IE10+ is:

```
#menuImage {
  background: url(../UserFile/test.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  width:100%;
  height:100%;

  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='5');          
}
```

I have therefore used the principle of an SVG object for IE instances that can then support Blurring and will position this behind the content for that area so it is a pseudo background. The method I have observered from another article is as below:

```
<svg class="blur-ie">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="../UserFile/test.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#blur)" preserveAspectRatio="slice"></image>
</svg>
```

However my issue is that I cannot replicate the background size cover effect to create this background wallpaper.

Can anyone assist in how I can achieve Background Cover effect via SVG method for Images. If this were a backwards compatibility issue I would not bother however this is IE10+ so is very frustrating.

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't need to support IE10 anymore as Microsoft no longer support it: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support.

Comment: But the principle is the same for IE 11 etc - they don't honour the Blur ability or the blur filter as old IE does. SVG will but I cant get the same effect on a background cover image in svg. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

One possibility could be to change the `height` and `width` properties dynamically using a JS library such as jQuery. Something like this should work:

**HTML:**

```
<svg class="blur-ie">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image id="svgImg" xlink:href="../UserFile/test.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#blur)" preserveAspectRatio="slice"></image>
</svg>
```

**jQuery:**

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version >= 10) {
   $(window).on('resize', function(){
      var winH = $(window).height();
      var winW = $(window).width();
      $('#svgImg').attr("height", winH);
      $('#svgImg').attr("height", winW);
   });
}
```

Although admittedly, this is very hacky.

> You could also look at using the **D3.js library**, which provides a JavaScript API for direct manipulation of SVG elements within the browser, in real time (link: [d3js.org](http://d3js.org/)).

Comment: Thanks for some direction I'll look into it and get back to you.